# How to customize MCBrowserViewController in swift for macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, multipeer-connectivity

Currently I browse a session using the following:

```
let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "service", session: p2pSession)
    
mcBrowser.delegate = self
mcBrowser.maximumNumberOfPeers = 1
listVC.presentAsModalWindow(mcBrowser)
```

Which produces a view:

[image]

I want to know if there's way to customize the appearance of the view controller before it's presented? For instance change the back ground of the list view to be dark instead of white. Or perhaps add an additional button to the window.

Comment: What do you want to customize? Please post the code you tried.

Comment: @Willeke I added additional details to the question. The code in the question is all I'm doing to make the window appear. I don't do anything further to change or modify it.

Comment: Is constructing your own browser an option?